# React - passing 'this' as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

Is there any side effect I do not see by doing this ?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    hello() {
        console.log("hello")
    }

    render() {
        return <Layout app={this}>
    }
}
```

So later on I can refer to this.props.app.hello (and others) from Layout ?

Comment: I see very few cases on why you should do that. Perhaps you're looking for [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you trying to use a function why no export and import? Or maybe try with redux?

Comment: you can pass all the props like this also `<Layout appProps={...this.props} />`

Comment: You will be sending unnecessary data to your component

Comment: It's not like the data has to travel, I just pass a reference to my App class instead.
I find it more convenient than passing the function I want to use directly (no need to bind and so on).


I do like the idea of using Context as it is for managing locales (and possibly authenticated state), so thanks @Bátido.

Comment: Do not do that. You are breaking the unidirectional flow of react, top down, in this way, if a child instance controls all the parent instance. Drill down the needed props instead, if through several levels, use react context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not safe.

React will not know how to watch for changes, so you may miss re-renders. React uses `===` to check for state changes, and `App` will always be `===` to `App`, even when state or properties change.

Take this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setState({text: 'default value'});
    }

    hello() {
        this.setState({...this.state, text: 'new value'});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.hello}>
                <Layout app={this}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.app.state.text}</div>
    }
}
```

When you click on the parent div, `this.hello` will be called, but the child component will not detect the state update, and may not re-render as expected. If it does re-render, it will be because the parent did. Relying on this will cause future bugs.

A safer pattern is to pass only what is needed into `props`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    //...

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.hello}>
                <Layout text={this.state.text}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.text}</div>
    }
}
```

This will update as expected.

Answer (score -1):

### Answer

*There's nothing wrong in passing functions as props, as I can see in your example, the only thing you have to do is make sure your function is bound to the current component like the following* [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

### Reference

[React: Passing Functions to Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: They're not passing a function, they're passing an entire class component.

Comment: Yeah dunno who upvoted this, not relevant to the question

Comment: I appreciate your comment @LionelRowe, as the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) says "Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism". I wanted to give a workaround by making this answer. If you have a constructive criticism please let me know in order to improve my technical skills.

Comment: I'm happy to expand on my comment. The info in this answer is correct (indeed, there is nothing wrong with passing functions as props), but the question being asked is not about functions. It is about passing a reference to a class-based component as a prop, specifically passing `this` to a child.

Comment: Passing a class is not safe because the class reference is to a mutable object and the reference never changes. React relies on state being treated as immutable, so passing a mutable class instance as a prop can cause issues. Hope this helps!